# D3 zoom callback

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback, zooming

Take [this timeless example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f) of D3 zoom. Shortened code below:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  ...;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 40])
    .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [width + 90, height + 100]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

...

d3.select("button")
    .on("click", resetted);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  view.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)));
}

function resetted() {
  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
```

In the D3 Zoom library one specifies the zoom behavior, then applies the zoom to the canvas or SVG target. How/where could I send a callback as a param to `zoomed()` without redefining the zoom behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked...

> How/where could I send a callback as a param?

... your question is dangerously *too broad*. But here is a possibility (out of many):

Suppose this simple callback function:

```
function callback(x){
    console.log(x);
}
```

We can send it to the `zoom` function changing the listener. So, instead of:

```
.on("zoom", zoomed);
```

We can do:

```
.on("zoom", function(){
    zoomed(callback)
});
```

And, in the `zoom` function, setting the callback argument. For instance, let's log the `d3.event.transform`:

```
function zoomed(fn) {
    fn(d3.event.transform);
    //rest of the code...
}
```

Here is a demo bl.ocks: http://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/38c77c024ba4cc42c86221117fed4164

Comment: About "too broad": Good point. In this answer the callback is attached to the zoom behavior when we run `.on("zoom", function() { zoomed(callback); })`. What I'm wondering about is how we could call zoom programmatically with a callback.